# How to delete viruses in the Ubuntu 12.10 in AVG antivirus

Tags: antivirus

I found viruses in the home folder, but I don't know which command is used to delete viruses in Ubuntu 12.10 using AVG antivirus. Can anyone tell me how to delete it?

Comment: Could you possible provide a screen-shot!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `~/.avg/config/default.cfg`

Search the section: `[test_config]` and add `clean = True`

Note: The avg folder will contain the version number.